# How can I investigate branches of solutions to polynomial matrix equations?

Tags: geometry, polynomials, soft-question, matrix-equations, applications

Are there some systematic approaches to find and/or describe solution spaces for polynomial equations involving matrices?

I am especially interested in equations of the type $${\bf X}^{N} = {\bf A}$$

For example when $\bf A$ represents a motion of some kind. Possibly affine transformations and geometrical projections.

I am able to numerically solve such equations by using smoothed fixed point methods. But this only gives me singular solutions and only depending on an initial guess. I suspect that there could exist large sets of solutions which could live in some subset of matrices ${\bf X} \in \mathcal X$. Especially interesting are solution spaces in which $\bf X$ are close to $\bf I$ in some sense. In my mind this should ensure a smooth sequence ${\bf X},{\bf X}^2, \cdots, {\bf X}^N$ which is of interest to my applications which mostly reside in the realms of computer graphics, image processing and video coding.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/73234/88984

Comment: Some months later... (maybe your issue has been solved now !). The fact that you are interested in matrices $X$ of the form $I+Y$ where $Y$ is "small" has triggered something in my mind: why not look for matrices of the form $X=\exp(P)$ for a certain $P$ which means a transformation of the issue into $\exp(NP)=A \iff \exp(N(I+Y))=I+B \iff $$I+Y=\tfrac{1}{N} \log(I+B)$. I know that logarithms of matrices are not that easy to handle, but in a certain vicinity of identity matrix, it works.